# JToolbarHelper contents disappearing when cache is enabled

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, custom-component, cache

I've setup my custom component using JToolbarHelper for navigation, following the standard set by base Joomla components.

Each view contains some variation of the following:

```
JToolbarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_CUSTOMCOMPONENT_MENU'), 'home');
JToolbarHelper::custom('view.task', 'options', 'options', 'Task', false);
```

Every `view.html.php`'s view extends a custom `JView` (`customComponentView`) which itself extends `JViewLegacy`, so functionally should be identical.

However, when I activate system cache to `ON - Conservative caching`, the toolbar renders as completely empty. No title, no buttons, nothing. the only way to have them reappear is to either turn off system cache, modify the code generating the buttons (although this fix only works until the page is changed/refreshed) or setup `JToolbarHelper` stuff in `customComponentView`.

I've checked the base components, and all of them are functioning appropriately, displaying the contents of their `JToolbarHelper` accordingly.